# ASP.NET MVC code first related table null reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, nullreferenceexception

I try to fetch user list from data base but some times 1 related table I call it is null and have not value for some user, so I get a null reference error.

```
@if (@row.UserProfile.DoctorDetail.Id != null) {
    @row.UserProfile.DoctorDetail.Expertise
}
```

ASP.NET MVC returns this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

So how can I check related table for null reference?

Comment: Is `row.UserProfile` or `row.UserProfile.DoctorDetail` null ?

Comment: You have to Check UserProfiler is not null. @if (@row.UserProfile !=null) { —- write your code here }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found Answer , i was edit my code to

```
 @if (@row.UserProfile.DoctorDetail != null)
 {
 @row.UserProfile.DoctorDetail.Expertise
 }
```

Fixed error